# WordPresas - Add string translations to an existing .po

Tags: wordpress, language-translation, poedit

I'm using a theme in which the Italian translation is partial. With an editor I added the new lines and generated the .mo with Poedit.
My doubt is about when I will download an update and when my translations will probably be overwritten.

Is there a way to avoid having to resynchronize new translations (the code uses domains in _e() functions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place your "custom" .po and .mo files into `/wp-content/languages/plugins` and it will override the plugin's original .po .mo files. So, even though you update the plugin, your custom translation files will be used.

For example, if you translate Akismet plugin to Italian, your files in `/wp-content/languages/plugins` will be

```
akismet-it_IT.mo
akismet-it_IT.po
```

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, you can add this code to your child theme's functions.php in order to do string translation. You can append this code as many as you want to translate the words. I added two lines (hello2 and hello3) at the end as an example.

```
// Translate Text
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text'); 
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text');

function translate_text($translated) { 
$translated = str_ireplace('Hello', 'Ciao', $translated); 
$translated = str_ireplace('Hello2', 'Ciao2', $translated); 
$translated = str_ireplace('Hello3', 'Ciao3', $translated);  

return $translated; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ozgur, and what about the possibility of merging the original (and partuial) .po with only my new and added strings?

Comment: I thought you already merged them. You should be able to merge them with poedit

Comment: Yes, but if a new version of the plug-in comes with maybe new strings, maybe some translated and some not, do I have to synchronize manually?

Comment: My solution only overrides the plugin's .po file with your custom .po file. Wordpress won't merge the plugin's updated strings with your custom ones. You can manually add the new strings to your .po file though.

Comment: @Zeno do you have only a few custom translations? If that's the case you can translate them using a function that you can add to your functions.php

Comment: Yes the number is limited.
Do you mean that I need to add a function to the theme sources?
Please note that I did not write the essay.

Comment: @Zeno I added an alternative string translation solution that you can do from your functions.php. You can use it if you have only a few translations.